# Oracle vs TDV Time Stamp Results vary

Tags: oracle, spotfire, tibco

I am building logic in Tibco's TDV to be used in Spotfire applications, in it, i have some calculated date requirements. The Screen shot below is the exact same Select statement to calculate the start of the Dell Fiscal year, in TDV, it gives the correct date as Feb 1, 2020. But oracle is Giving a different date and i require oracle validation before promoting to TDV, so this is failing a required validation step.  I have confirmed all default formats are set in both TDV and oracle developer.
If there is a better method as well to determine fiscal start dates please share.  Dell dates are not standard quarters, each is only 91 days, making a 364 day year. Last years start date would have been Feb 2, 2019,  so this year its Feb 1, next will be Jan 31. and so on... I tried to add a Tag for TDV, but could not because of < 1500 rep points.

```
Select 
to_Date('2019-02-02', 'YYYY-MM-DD')  + ((CAST(Current_Date -to_Date('2019-02-02', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS INT)/364)* 364) 
From Dual
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really clear on what you're trying to do with this logic, but it seems like the difference is that Oracle does not do **integer arithmetic**, while TDV does. As a result, in TDV, it seems like the expression `(CAST(Current_Date -to_Date('2019-02-02', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS INT)/364)` evaluates to 1, is that right?

But in Oracle, INTs are not first-class data types - an INT divided by an untyped number is a (floating-point) NUMBER. The expression `(CAST(Current_Date -to_Date('2019-02-02', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS INT)/364)` evaluates to 1.85714285714286.

If you want Oracle to treat a number as an INT, you have to truncate it yourself - ROUND, FLOOR, CEIL, etc. I think this query will do what you want.

```
Select 
to_Date('2019-02-02', 'YYYY-MM-DD') + FLOOR((Current_Date - to_Date('2019-02-02', 'YYYY-MM-DD'))/364)*364 
From Dual;
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, i have not considered the difference of INT between the two.  Spotfire is similar to Power BI so the TDV engine (data services engine) is pulling data for it to analyize,  I have been requested to make a fiscal scorecard that spans back several years and forward for a forcast.  One of the markers is to ID the start dates of quarters / years / weeks etc. in which is need a solid fiscal year start date.  I did not want to hard code these dates so that they can be used in the future without changes to the production environment.

Comment: I will research your solution and if so will +1 you.

Comment: Also yes, that date would evaluate to 1 today, but next year 2 with the date floating -1 day each year

Comment: Checked yours as the solution as it answers why theres is a delta

Answer (score 0):

If you need to add a specific number of days to a date, you can just add that number to the date and it will add the number of days

```sql
SELECT TO_DATE ('2019-02-02', 'YYYY-MM-DD') + 364 FROM DUAL;
```

But, instead of adding a number of days (364) to your date, it might be a better idea to use Oracle's `ADD_MONTHS` function. This will also take into account leap years so you do not need to factor that into any special logic. By adding 12 months, you can add a year to a date or by adding 3 you can add a quarter to a date. Using this function should help make your queries more accurate.

```sql
--Fiscal Year that will be starting this calendar year
SELECT ADD_MONTHS (TRUNC (CURRENT_DATE, 'Y') + 1, 1) AS start_date FROM DUAL;

--Fiscal Year start dates for last, current, and next calendar year
SELECT start_date,
       ADD_MONTHS (start_date, 12) - 1                    AS end_date,
       (ADD_MONTHS (start_date, 12) - 1) - start_date     AS number_of_days
  FROM (    SELECT ADD_MONTHS (ADD_MONTHS (TRUNC (CURRENT_DATE, 'Y') + 1, 1), 12 * (LEVEL - 2))    AS start_date
              FROM DUAL
        CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 3);

--Fiscal Year quarter start dates for last, current, and next calendar year
SELECT 'FY' || EXTRACT (YEAR FROM start_date)
           AS fiscal_year,
       ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY EXTRACT (YEAR FROM start_date) ORDER BY start_date)
           AS quarter_number,
       start_date,
       ADD_MONTHS (start_date, 3) - 1
           AS end_date,
       (ADD_MONTHS (start_date, 3) - 1) - start_date
           AS number_of_days
  FROM (    SELECT ADD_MONTHS (ADD_MONTHS (TRUNC (CURRENT_DATE, 'Y') + 1, 1), 3 * (LEVEL - 5))    AS start_date
              FROM DUAL
        CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 12);
```

Output

```sql
SQL> --Fiscal Year that will be starting this calendar year
SQL> SELECT ADD_MONTHS (TRUNC (CURRENT_DATE, 'Y') + 1, 1) AS start_date FROM DUAL;

   START_DATE
_____________
02-FEB-20

SQL>
SQL> --Fiscal Year start dates for last, current, and next calendar year
SQL> SELECT start_date,
  2         ADD_MONTHS (start_date, 12) - 1                    AS end_date,
  3         (ADD_MONTHS (start_date, 12) - 1) - start_date     AS number_of_days
  4    FROM (    SELECT ADD_MONTHS (ADD_MONTHS (TRUNC (CURRENT_DATE, 'Y') + 1, 1), 12 * (LEVEL - 2))    AS start_date
  5                FROM DUAL
  6          CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 3);

   START_DATE     END_DATE    NUMBER_OF_DAYS
_____________ ____________ _________________
02-FEB-19     01-FEB-20                  364
02-FEB-20     01-FEB-21                  365
02-FEB-21     01-FEB-22                  364

SQL>
SQL> --Fiscal Year quarter start dates for last, current, and next calendar year
SQL> SELECT 'FY' || EXTRACT (YEAR FROM start_date)
  2             AS fiscal_year,
  3         ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY EXTRACT (YEAR FROM start_date) ORDER BY start_date)
  4             AS quarter_number,
  5         start_date,
  6         ADD_MONTHS (start_date, 3) - 1
  7             AS end_date,
  8         (ADD_MONTHS (start_date, 3) - 1) - start_date
  9             AS number_of_days
 10    FROM (    SELECT ADD_MONTHS (ADD_MONTHS (TRUNC (CURRENT_DATE, 'Y') + 1, 1), 3 * (LEVEL - 5))    AS start_date
 11                FROM DUAL
 12          CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 12);

   FISCAL_YEAR    QUARTER_NUMBER    START_DATE     END_DATE    NUMBER_OF_DAYS
______________ _________________ _____________ ____________ _________________
FY2019                         1 02-FEB-19     01-MAY-19                   88
FY2019                         2 02-MAY-19     01-AUG-19                   91
FY2019                         3 02-AUG-19     01-NOV-19                   91
FY2019                         4 02-NOV-19     01-FEB-20                   91
FY2020                         1 02-FEB-20     01-MAY-20                   89
FY2020                         2 02-MAY-20     01-AUG-20                   91
FY2020                         3 02-AUG-20     01-NOV-20                   91
FY2020                         4 02-NOV-20     01-FEB-21                   91
FY2021                         1 02-FEB-21     01-MAY-21                   88
FY2021                         2 02-MAY-21     01-AUG-21                   91
FY2021                         3 02-AUG-21     01-NOV-21                   91
FY2021                         4 02-NOV-21     01-FEB-22                   91

12 rows selected.
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it will only partially work because the Dell quarters never fall below 91 days.  But additionally, how would you break down further to add fiscal week of the quarter?